# Visual Studio HTML Designer isn't working properly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4

I'm learning **Bootstrap 4** with **Visual Studio 2017**.
Before Visual Studio, I was writing in Notepad. I created an HTML file with *Web Forms Editor* and copied same codes in that file.

I also properly attached the *Bootstrap.min.css* file which I have downloaded the latest version (v4.1.1) from
https://getbootstrap.com/.

The problem is, when I open the file in Chrome, it's working as it should be but, the columns break down when I open the file in Visual Studio's **Designer Mode**.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717610/bootstrap-not-working-properly-with-visual-studio) question but the only suggestion was about the path of the stylesheet. I have checked my stylesheet path and there was no problem.

I will be glad if someone can help.

Edit: I recognized that some Bootstrap 4 classes also not working.

Here is my attachments.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Deneme</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that doesn't work in the designer

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you are using correct **js** file for your bootstrap version. Sometimes due to the lack of mismatching version of **css** and **js** it creats error and for this reason bootstrap doesn't work. 
you can use content delivery network [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/) for getting your exact version of **css** and **js**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the scripts but still not working. I added my attachments to my post.

Comment: The Bootstrap grid system doesn't need any JavaScript.